# Why does javascript not see the "selected" attribute on my select option?

Tags: javascript, html

**Short version:**

After inserting a select element with options into the DOM with an AJAX call the "selected" attribute on my option isn't recognized by the JavaScript. It's as if it's not there even though looking at it in Firebug I can see that it is.

**Long version:**

I'm using a jQuery plugin that generates a "multi select" (select imitation with checkboxes pretty much) based on an actual html select with options that can have a "selected" attribute. The plugin checks if the selected attribute exists by doing

```
$(this).attr('selected') == true
```

and if it exists it sets the corresponding checkbox to checked. This all works when I load the page normally. I also need to reload the data if the user chooses to filter it and here is where the problem is. The new data is fetched via AJAX and the plugin is reapplied to new markup but the "selected" attribute isn't considered present **even though it's there just like before**. Other attributes work fine but "selected" bizarrely enough doesn't. This is the markup both when it works and when it doesn't.

`<option value="1" selected="selected" warning="true"> text</option>`

I'm really scratching my head over this. Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. We use a js combiner and apparently moving the include call to a different file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Forget jQuery's confusingly named `attr()` method and attributes in general, and instead just use the `selected` property of the option, which is a Boolean and works in all major browsers released since 1996:

```
// Assuming the select list is stored in a variable called select
alert( select.options[0].selected );
```

If you must use jQuery to get the option, here's the equivalent:

```
alert( $(this)[0].selected );
```

Attributes are almost never what you want, since they are incorrectly implemented in IE and only ever represent the **initial** value of a some aspect of the element, not the current value. jQuery's `attr()` method generally uses properties internally.

Comment: I have and it also returns false. Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: In which case, the option is definitely not selected. Perhaps the select list is no longer a multiple select list? More code is needed.

Comment: the "multiple select list" is not yet generated. this is a regular select with regular option elements in it. I'm thinking it could do with it having been dynamically added to the DOM but I don't see how that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: The most reliable cross-browser way to add options is using the `options` collection. `var opts = select.options; opts[opts.length] = new Option("Option text", "option_value", true, true);` (the `true` values make the option selected).

Comment: The options are added as part of a larger section of markup returned from the server as a partial view (ASP.NET)  and then jacked into the page. What baffles me is that none of that should matter to the plugin parsing the option elements. Something that points to this being my (or the plugin author) screw up is that this problem doesn't seem to be browser specific as it presents itself in all of the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

why are you comparing to `true`? the `"selected"` value is `"selected"`, not `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your getting the element where Selected == True but selected is actually 'selected'.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to check if an option is selected, type the following:

```
if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
 ...
}
```

So, if you want to detect all selected options you could use:

$("select option:selected").each(function () {
  ...
});

Perhaps, this fixes the problem.